# The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 11.8.0

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I would like to add notification with firebase on my app.
I followed a video on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx7hemn3FY4)
But I have an error when I do the same thing in my flutter project : The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 11.8.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

I tried several things as you can see in comment.

Project gradle :

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'

}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        /*
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        */
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.0"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

App Gradle :

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.weatherapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //Implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1'
    //Implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But none of these changes works. Do you have an other idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the similar issue, where in the error message it states that

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but **resolves to 11.8.0**. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Resolved **resolves to 11.8.0**

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //Implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1'
    //Implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'.  // <<--- Add this
}
```

I solved my isssue by adding the line

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'.  // <<--- Add this
```

Also if this doesn't fix the issue please add this line;

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

at the end of the same file like below;

```
...

dependencies {
  ....
}

....

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Let me know if it solved our issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Above didn't help for me. Had to use this aswell: 
    com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

Comment: @cfl Where do I add that?

Comment: Where does the line have to be added?

Comment: Please add the given line in the build.gradle file;

android/app/build.gradle

And if you have to add this at the end of the same file;

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

Answer (score 3):

This conflict happens because of using older libraries solution is use latest one.
In my case i was using firebase version 16.0.0 , current latest is 16.0.4 (07-02-2019)

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

rather than this

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

Comment: yeah same always history with googles libraries...thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the firebase and other Google services are the same or not.

form
    `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'`

to

```
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.1'`
```

Comment: Why is the last line enclosed in single quotes?