# Android 11 app crash with "The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 12451000 but found 4323000"

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, android-manifest, android-11

My app starts crashing on Android 11 devices with the following error message **"The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 12451000 but found 4323000"**. I aware of such issues and I have already define correct value inside the manifest file  as follows:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

If I follow google_play_services_version I can found the expected value

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">12451000</integer>
```

With the help of firebase analytics, I can confirm that it is happening with Android 11 devices only.
[image: impacted end user device]

From the various SO posts I tried the following things so far:

1- Update all used play service and Firebase dependencies to the latest available version.

2- Used tools: replace with build clean process, in the meta-data tag as follows for both app module as well as for wear module:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        tools:replace="android:value" />
```

3- Check all used 3rd part libs/SDK's manifest files for @integer/google_play_services_version but all are redirecting to the expected value i.e. 12451000.

Following are the build.gradle files:
A- build.gradle {:app}-

```
apply from: '../release-config.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'android-release-plugin'
apply plugin: 'testfairy'
apply from: '../sonar.gradle'
apply from: '../jacoco.gradle'
// Add the Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android.testOptions {
 unitTests.all {
    jacoco {
        includeNoLocationClasses = true
    }
}
unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
tasks.sonarqube.dependsOn jacocoTestReport


android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
ndkVersion "16.1.4479499"

kapt {
    javacOptions {
        option("-Adagger.gradle.incremental")
        option("-Adagger.formatGeneratedSource=disabled")
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx”
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_BASE", ‘”————“’
    buildConfigField "String", "LOCUSLABS_ACCOUNT_ID", ‘”——“’
    buildConfigField "String", "GCM_SENDER_ID", ‘”———“’
    buildConfigField "String", "GRAB_ID", ‘”———“’
    buildConfigField "String", "GCT_CONVERSION_ID", ‘”———“’
    buildConfigField "String", "GCT_LABEL", ‘”———“’
    buildConfigField "String", "GCT_VALUE", ‘”——“’
}

signingConfigs {

}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix "(Debuggable)"
        debuggable true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        zipAlignEnabled true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
      'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
    }
}

flavorDimensions 'environment'

productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_BASE", ‘”——————‘

        def internalVersion = 
         releaseConfig.getAppVersion().internalVersion
        resValue "string", "app_name", "xx (Test) ${internalVersion}"
    }

    stage {
        applicationIdSuffix ".stage"
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_BASE", ‘”—————“’—

        def internalVersion = 
        releaseConfig.getAppVersion().internalVersion
        resValue "string", "app_name", "xx (Stage) ${internalVersion}"
    }

    prod {
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_BASE", ‘”———“’——
        buildConfigField "String", "LOCUSLABS_ACCOUNT_ID", ‘”———“’
        buildConfigField "String", "GCM_SENDER_ID", ‘”——“’
        buildConfigField "String", "GRAB_ID", ‘”——“’
        buildConfigField "String", "GCT_CONVERSION_ID", ‘”———“’
        buildConfigField "String", "GCT_LABEL", ‘”———“’
    }
}

 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/**rxjava.properties**'
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

testfairyConfig {
    apiKey “———————“
}

testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
}

def powermock_version = "2.0.2"
def daggerVersion = "2.16"
def leak_canary_version = "2.0-beta-1"

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation project(':common')
implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.4.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.2"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:17.0.0"
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.2'
implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'

// need by grab sdk
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0') {
    // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp peer-dependency module and define 
   your own module import
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.10'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5'
implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'


implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
implementation 'org.kamranzafar:jtar:2.2'
implementation 'org.tukaani:xz:1.5'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
implementation(name: 'locuslabs-android-sdk-2.3.10', ext: 'aar') {
    transitive = true
}
 implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-core:0.38.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-widget:0.38.0'
compileOnly 'com.facebook.litho:litho-annotations:0.38.0'
kapt 'com.facebook.litho:litho-processor:0.38.0'

// Firebase Dependencies
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0"
// Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
// Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1"

// Grab Dependencies
implementation(name: 'grab-framework-1.1.33', ext: 'aar')
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.16.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
implementation 'org.kamranzafar:jtar:2.2'
implementation group: 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber', name: 
'libphonenumber', version: '8.4.1'
implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
api 'com.wunderlist:sliding-layer:1.2.5'

// Background Process
implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.4.2'

// Dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"

// Paging
implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.2'

// Lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0"

// Utils
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

//For updating styles attributes dynamically
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:paris:1.7.1'

// A memory leak detection library.
debugImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${leak_canary_version}"
implementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-object-watcher-android:${leak_canary_version}"
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

wearApp project(':wearable')

//Test
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'

testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:${powermock_version}"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:${powermock_version}"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:${powermock_version}"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:${powermock_version}"

androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}

androidTestImplementation('androidx.test:runner:1.3.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation ("com.github.tomeees:scrollpicker:1.7.4")

 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

B- Top-level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

repositories {       
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    maven { url "http://www.bugsense.com/gradle/" }
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    google()
    }

    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    classpath 'com.dminc.gradle:android-release-plugin:1.1.0.6'
    classpath 'com.testfairy.plugins.gradle:testfairy:2.0'
    classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

    }

     allprojects {
     repositories {
     flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
     mavenLocal()
     mavenCentral()
     google()
     }
     }
```

I am checking for Play service availability from my Splash screen {luncher activity}. I even tried to catch thrown exception by applying try-catch and able to catch it successfully but app still crashing :

I am checking for Play service availability from my Splash screen {luncher activity}. I even tried to catch thrown exception by applying try catch and able to catch it successfully but app still crashing :

```
    public static int checkPlayServices(Context activity) {
     int retValue;

    try {
        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
        Timber.tag(TAG).d(  "This device is supported with api version%s",
                                                            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getClientVersion(activity));

        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                retValue = PLAY_STORE_RESOLVABLE_ERROR;
                Timber.tag(TAG).d( "This device is supported but can be resolved.");
            } else {
                Timber.tag(TAG).d(  "This device is not supported and cannot be resolved.");
                retValue = PLAY_STORE_UN_SUPPORT;
            }
        } else {
            retValue = PLAY_STORE_AVAILABLE;
        }
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {
        Timber.tag(TAG).d( "This device Throws Illegal state Exception. Probably caused by google_play_services_version");
        Timber.tag(TAG).e( e.getMessage());
        retValue = PLAY_STORE_VERSION_ERROR;
    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        Timber.tag(TAG).d(  "This device Throws Exception. Exact Reason is unknown");
        Timber.tag(TAG).e(  e.getMessage());
        retValue = PLAY_STORE_ERROR;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

I am able to catch but app still got crashes which leads me to another idea that maybe some other SDK dependency is throwing this exception. I check all 3rd SDK's and found that two other SDK's {Facebook and Braintree payments is also checking for Google play service}.

_ I have removed both SDK's but still getting crash.

Note: This crash is happening only on Android 11 devices/emulators for all build versions.

Now I have no option to try. Any leads would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Himanshu not yet.

Comment: which type of app has this issue debug or release ?

Comment: @Harkal Both types.

Comment: did you reverse enginner and see the values ?

Comment: I checked the value and by hovering in Manifest and it leads me to the right expected values.

Comment: Same here I am getting issue in release and getting the right value after analyze an apk.

Comment: maybe you should open up a bug in issuetracker for android and see what they have to say.post all the findings and logs with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YEAH!
I found solution.
The problem was with library:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1"
```

Just replace to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
```

Above library loaded the "basement library" and finally we have two "basement" libraries.
First was loaded by "play services" library and second loaded by "firebase-core"

For more click below url:
[The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 11.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485608/the-library-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-basement-is-being-requested-by)

and this

https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/1026

If this answer did not help you then read about gradle and force libraries inside  `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'`
like below:

```
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3") {
        force = true
    }
```

**NOTE:**
The "force" method was deprecated you must to use new features

Comment: Sound like a solution. As I have seen "basement library" in some logs. I will definitely give it a try and will update you soon. Thanks.

Comment: @AdarshYadav YEAH , before to fix I read more about this crash with Google sensei but they did not help me , finally I found above link and fix, so if my solution worked please mark as solution
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Issue has been fixed.

Just change the order of the meta tag. The version tag should always come first.

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_key"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
```

Comment: Tried, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **meta tag** in place the answer in most cases would lie in to have a combination of library versions which are compatible and updates of deprecated methods.

You have mentioned following in your build.gradle :

> implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3')

One possible reason that I got familiar with on **Android 11** with above Facebook SDK version is use of deprecated method *activateApp* leads to mentioned issue.

Update method **AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);** to :

```
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getApplication());
```

Let us know if it worked for you.

Comment: Are you saying that if I change the activateApp call it can solve the crash on play services? I'm asking because I see this crash in my crashlytics, but I can't reproduce in my device, so I'll have to make the change, deploy it to production and see if works.

Comment: Yes, it was worth making that change on my end.

Comment: I made the change and it's going to production in the next days, I'll comment here the updates